# Can I retrieve nested data in the pom file when filtering resources with maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven

I am interested in pulling information from the first member nested in a list from my pom, eg:

```
<project>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <version>the-info-i-want<version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> ... </dependency>
    <dependency> ... </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I found out that I can perform placeholder expansion on resource files using **maven-resource-plugin**'s filtering feature in the resource goal.

All examples I see only go scavenging for the usual suspects: `project.version`, `project.artifactId`. The documentation says that placeholder resolution is simply making getter calls of the underlying model. It doesn't make any reference to limitations of the language provided for name/property resolution.

- Is it possible to dive into lists?
- Is it possible to perform filtering/selection? (like JsonPath or XPath)
- I mentioned the first member but is it safe to assume that the order is deterministic even after packaging?

All I want to do is populate a properties file with the name (artifactId) and version of one dependency

I've tried

```
# metadata.properties
dep_version = ${project.dependencies[0].version
dep_version = ${project.dependencies{0}.version
dep_version = ${project.dependencies(0).version
dep_version = ${project.dependencies.get(0).version
```

I know that I can also grab a hold of this information by programmatically accessing the meta file at `META-INF/maven/{groupId}/{artifactId}/pom.xml` and parsing that XML to collect whatever I want. I would just want to avoid adding such scavenging code if this can be resolved at the package goal which is where it belongs

Comment: The first questions which comes into my mind: Why do you like to do that? What is the purpose of the whole thing cause you have not explained the reason of ding such things?

Comment: Some models of my project are going to be stored in a serialized fashion with associated metadata for future inspection and probably auditing. The models are all provided through a library which I do not control (and I must also always keep up to date with). However, I do know that the library itself is well versioned and that I can use this metadata to correctly identify my output. I want to be able to retrieve this information without having to write code (that I would have to maintain) if I can find another way that is already provided by maven (which is in charge of versioning)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your explanation but why don't you implement some unit/integration tests to check the behaviour? I don't full understand what the real problem is but it sounds like a compatibility issue...

Comment: unit tests and integration tests have nothing to do with long term storage, only with current behavior. Models change over time and the information stored (non-relational) must be **qualified** for deserialization.